# How to "Show my current location on google maps, when I open the ViewController?" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using Google maps sdk of iOS(Swift).

Has anyone know how to "Show my current location on google maps, when I open the ViewController"?

Actually it just like Google Maps App. When you open the Google Maps, the blue spot will show your current location. You don't need press the "myLocationButton" in first time.

So this is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

class GoogleMapsViewer: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let didFindMyLocation = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(23.931735,longitude: 121.082711, zoom: 7)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)

        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        // GOOGLE MAPS SDK: BORDER
        let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 45.0, right: 0.0)
        mapView.padding = mapInsets

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        // GOOGLE MAPS SDK: COMPASS
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true

        // GOOGLE MAPS SDK: USER'S LOCATION
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
}


// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
extension GoogleMapsViewer: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }
        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 20, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        } 
    }
}
```

Anyone help? Thank you so much!

Comment: this is enough for shw current location   // GOOGLE MAPS SDK: COMPASS
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true

        // GOOGLE MAPS SDK: USER'S LOCATION
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

Comment: Yes, it's enough for show current location. But can I set camera in my current location?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> For **Swift 3.x** solution, please check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058423/2545465)

First all of you have to enter a key in Info.plist file
`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

[image]

After adding this key just make a `CLLocationManager` variable and do the following

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

class YourControllerClass: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //Your map initiation code 
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    self.view = mapView
    self.mapView?.myLocationEnabled = true

    //Location Manager code to fetch current location
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


//Location Manager delegates
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude((location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 17.0)

    self.mapView?.animateToCameraPosition(camera)

    //Finally stop updating location otherwise it will come again and again in this delegate
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

When you run the code you will get a pop up of Allow and Don't Allow for location. Just click on Allow and you will see your current location.

Make sure to do this on a **device** rather than simulator. If you are using simulator, you have to choose some custom location and then only you will be able to see the blue dot.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Use this code,

You miss the `addObserver` method and  some content,

`viewDidLoad`:

```
mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;

mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: .New, context: nil)

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  });
```

Observer Method:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] == nil {

        let location = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as CLLocation
        gmsMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(location.coordinate, zoom: 16)
    }
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: I liked the approach to check if oldValue is nil.

Comment: @iyyappan-ravi is there any reason to `dispatch_async` `myLocationEnabled = YES`? I've seen this already somewhere else, but still I'm not sure why this could be needed.

Answer (score 8):

- first add the following to your info.plist

  1. NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
  2. LSApplicationQueriesSchemes  (of type array and add two items to this array 
     item 0 : googlechromes ,
     item 1 : comgooglemaps
- second go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start and follow the steps till step 5
- last thing to do after you set up every thing is to go to your ViewController and paste the following

  ```
  import UIKit
  import GoogleMaps

  class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

      //Outlets
      @IBOutlet var MapView: GMSMapView!

      //Variables
      var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          initializeTheLocationManager()
          self.MapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
      }

      func initializeTheLocationManager() {
          locationManager.delegate = self
          locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
          locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      }

      func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

          var location = locationManager.location?.coordinate

          cameraMoveToLocation(toLocation: location)

      }

      func cameraMoveToLocation(toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?) {
          if toLocation != nil {
              MapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: toLocation!, zoom: 15)
          }
      }

  }
  ```

( don't forget to add a view in the storyboard and connect it to the MapViw)

now you can build and run to see your current location on the google map just like when you open the Google Map App

enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.0 or above** 
For displaying user location (**Blue Marker**) in GMS map View make sure you have got Location Permission and add this line

```
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RxCoreLocation](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxCoreLocation):

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import RxCoreLocation
import RxSwift

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    private var mapView: GMSMapView?
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 0, longitude: 0, zoom: 17.0)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
        view = mapView

        manager.rx
            .didUpdateLocations
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
                guard let location = $0.locations.last else { return }
                let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 17.0)
                self?.mapView?.animate(to: camera)
                self?.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI

```
struct GoogleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @State var coordinator = Coordinator()

  func makeUIView(context _: Context) -> GMSMapView {
    let view = GMSMapView(frame: .zero)
    view.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    view.animate(toZoom: 18)
    view.addObserver(coordinator, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: .new, context: nil)
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: GMSMapView, context _: UIViewRepresentableContext<GoogleMapView>) {}

  func makeCoordinator() -> GoogleMapView.Coordinator {
    return coordinator
  }

  static func dismantleUIView(_ uiView: GMSMapView, coordinator: GoogleMapView.Coordinator) {
    uiView.removeObserver(coordinator, forKeyPath: "myLocation")
  }

  final class Coordinator: NSObject {
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
      if let location = change?[.newKey] as? CLLocation, let mapView = object as? GMSMapView {
        mapView.animate(toLocation: location.coordinate)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after the line:

```
view = mapView
```

add:

```
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

This will enable your location:

NOTE:- Locations on Simulator are preset for particular places, you can not change them. if you want to use current location you have to use real device for testing.

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentlocationlbl: UILabel!

    var mapView:GMSMapView!

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager! = CLLocationManager.init()
    var geoCoder:GMSGeocoder!
    var marker:GMSMarker!

    var initialcameraposition:GMSCameraPosition!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.mapView = GMSMapView()
        self.geoCoder = GMSGeocoder()
        self.marker = GMSMarker()
        self.initialcameraposition = GMSCameraPosition()

        // Create gms map view------------->
        mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 414, height: 667)
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.isBuildingsEnabled = false

        mapView.isTrafficEnabled = false
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
        // create cureent location label---------->

        self.currentlocationlbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        self.currentlocationlbl.numberOfLines = 3
        self.currentlocationlbl.text = "Fetching address.........!!!!!"

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        if locationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization))
        {
            self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        if #available(iOS 9, *)
        {
            self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }
        else
        {
            //fallback earlier version
        }

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.marker.title = "Current Location"
        self.marker.map = self.mapView

        // Gps button add mapview

        let gpbtn:UIButton! = UIButton.init()
        gpbtn.frame = CGRect(x: 374, y: 500, width: 40, height: 40)
        gpbtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gpsAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        gpbtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"gps.jpg"), for: .normal)
        self.mapView.addSubview(gpbtn)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        var location123 = CLLocation()
        location123 = locations[0]
        let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D! = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location123.coordinate.latitude, location123.coordinate.longitude)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: coordinate, zoom: 16.0)

        self.mapView.camera = camera
        self.initialcameraposition = camera
        self.marker.position = coordinate
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()    
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition)
    {
        self.currentAddres(position.target)
    }

    func currentAddres(_ coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void
    {
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { (response, error) in

            if error == nil
            {
                if response != nil
                {
                    let address:GMSAddress! = response!.firstResult()

                    if address != nil
                    {
                        let addressArray:NSArray! = address.lines! as NSArray

                        if addressArray.count > 1
                        {
                            var convertAddress:AnyObject! = addressArray.object(at: 0) as AnyObject!
                            let space = ","
                            let convertAddress1:AnyObject! = addressArray.object(at: 1) as AnyObject!
                            let country:AnyObject! = address.country as AnyObject!

                            convertAddress = (((convertAddress.appending(space) + (convertAddress1 as! String)) + space) + (country as! String)) as AnyObject

                            self.currentlocationlbl.text = "\(convertAddress!)".appending(".")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            self.currentlocationlbl.text = "Fetching current location failure!!!!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should seriously take a look at guards in Swift https://medium.com/@chris_dus/the-guard-statement-in-swift-fdad41b08798. It's one of the first thing you learn when taking proper classes