# Current location in not working in Google Map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, cllocationmanager

I have integrated google map in swift 3, when map screen appear than current location in not showing, i have added two keys in .plist file and also set CLLocationManager delegate and requestAlwaysAuthorization

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
    var marker: GMSMarker?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.title = "MapVC"
         self.doSetupUI()
         self.searchLocation()
   }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         let locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
         locationManager.delegate = self
         locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   }



func doGoogleMapSetup(lat : Double , lng : Double) {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude:lng, zoom:16)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera:camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
    marker.snippet = ""
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
    marker.map = mapView

    let arrPoints : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    arrPoints.add(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "addressPoints"))

    for i in 0..<arrPoints.count {
        let path : String = (arrPoints.object(at: i)as! NSMutableArray).object(at: 0) as! String
        let route : GMSPath = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: path)!
        let polyLine : GMSPolyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: route)
        polyLine.strokeWidth = 2.0
        polyLine.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        polyLine.map = mapView
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "location"? Are you talking about a place mark, indicating user location? Are you trying to get the center coordinates of the map? Or something else?

Comment: hiii, i m trying get user's current location

Comment: func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        let latitude: Double = newLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude: Double = newLocation.coordinate.longitude
        currentlat = latitude
        currentlong = longitude
      
    }

Comment: @Dhanraj: You shouldn't need the map to get the user's location. locationManager.location should give you the Geocoordinates of your user.

Comment: Hiii, before some days its working perfect and now its not working in my other app have same problem

Comment: What's the problem? What does print(locationManager.location) show in your console? Also, are you running in the simulator?

Comment: i m running in iPod and locationManager.location print "nil"   my app is not listed in Location Service in Settings

Comment: That means that the device is not tracking the user's locations. I've built lots of location-based apps, and the most common problem I run into, is that you call the startLocating method (which prompts the user to allow location tracking) in the same ViewController as the location request. What this can do, is have the app ask the manager for the location, before it has the location. Does that make sense?

Comment: Though there are other reasons why it may come back nil: the app doesn't have permission, the phone/simulator's GPS is broken, for instance.

Comment: when screen appear than allow location tracking prompts comes i have clicked on "Allow" option but there nothing happened

Comment: You should also call locationManager.startLocating(). This tells the device to start tracking the user's current location. I will leave a more detailed answer, describing a race condition I've frequently encountered, as an answer below. It will take me a minute.

Comment: @Dhanraj where are you calling `doGoogleMapSetup`

Comment: @dylanthelion  don't need any `CLLocationManager` in case of google maps. All we just need is to add keys in plist.

Comment: @Dhanraj Check the answer I posted. tested on iOS 10 device, working fine

Comment: Hello all, issue solved, there some code sequence problem and thanks to all for help

Answer (score 25):

For showing current location we don't need any location manager in case of `GoogleMaps`. All we need is to add one of the keys or both in the **.plist**. So make sure the key is there. I have used `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow location</string>
```

[image]

Also make sure that you have called `GMSServices` `provideAPIKey` method and replaced with the **API_KEY** you generated in google developer console. Also all the relevant Google APIs as per requirement should be enabled.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
       return true
    }
```

So, I am assuming you have done all the settings and things right in google developer console.

By just writing the below line in your controller where you have made the `GoogleMap` can show the location allow/disallow prompt and take the permission of the user.

```
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

However this will not animate your map to your current location. But you can manually drag the map to check the current location and you will see a blue dot at your current location.

But now we also want to animate to the current location whenever we load that `ViewController`. Now the need for `CLLocationManager` arrives. So that in its `didUpdateLocation` delegate, we can fetch the current location and can just animate the graph to the current location.

So here is my complete controller.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController,GMSMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.delegate = self

        //Location Manager code to fetch current location
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //Location Manager delegates
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude:(location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom:14)
        mapView.animate(to: camera)

        //Finally stop updating location otherwise it will come again and again in this delegate
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }
}
```

Another way of doing is not using the `didUpdateLocation` and not using the location manager is just by using the `GMSMapViewDelegate` delegate method `mapViewDidFinishTileRendering`

```
func mapViewDidFinishTileRendering(_ mapView: GMSMapView) {
    let location = mapView.myLocation
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude:(location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom:14)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)
}
```

It will be called everytime the map rendering is finished.
But this comes with a limitation, it will always bring you to the current location whenever you drag/pinch/zoom map as the rendering finish everytime you play with map. So, you can just implement some kind of `bool` variable logic here.

You can get your location by using

```
let yourCurrentLocation = mapView.myLocation
```

Make sure to do this on a device rather than simulator. If you are using simulator, you have to choose some custom location and then only you will be able to see the blue dot.

[image]

I already gave this type of answer. Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626649/how-to-show-my-current-location-on-google-maps-when-i-open-the-viewcontroller/38627279#38627279). But that was in Swift 2.x. The one which I posted in this answer is in Swift 3.x

Comment: Awesome. I would like to know, is it necessary to add the plist `Privacy - ..` if you are using the `didUpdateLocation ` ?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to add the entries in plist in order to activate the location access for the respective app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit detailed, so I'd like to leave it in a full answer. This is the most common reason I have encountered for a nil location, since figuring out the basics, a few years ago. So, you call CLLocationManager.startLocating(), in your viewDidLoad. Then you call the method that sets up your map. Sometimes this works, and sometimes it doesn't, because of a race condition caused by the amount of time it takes the CLLocationManager to set up permissions, on the one hand, and access the user's location, in another part of the code. Let's look at an order of events, where it doesn't work:

1) you call requestAlwaysAuthroization and startLocating
2) User permissions setup is triggered on one thread
3) In your ViewController, you request the user's location, to set up your map
4) It comes back nil
5) NOW, step 2 finishes, and the app has access to the user's location, but it's too late

The core problem, is that the process that starts with requesting permissions and location, takes more than a few milliseconds. And if your view is already set up, it takes few milliseconds for it to go through the methods in your viewDidLoad. By the time you have the location you need, you've already requested it. This has caused me too many crashes, in my location-based apps.

My workaround, has been to craft a singleton CLLocationManager, make my starting view a delegate, and requestAlwaysAuthorization and startLocating, in that view. That way, when I get to the view that needs the location, the app has already started locating, and the locationManager.location is not nil.

This is an approach that will obviously not work for every app. If you need clarification, let me know, and if you need code, as well. I have a few public iO git repos, with projects where I have encountered and fixed this problem.

Comment: Hiii dylanthelion,  thanks for help. can u plz share demos?

Comment: Check out the Develop branch of this unfinished app:
https://github.com/dylanthelion/AssassinationClient
The two things to look at are LocationManager.swift, which is a singleton and calls the methods you need to start tracking location in startLocating, and LoginViewController, which is the first view in the app, and starts tracking location immediately on app startup.

Comment: Also, it's pre-Swift 3, and may or may not build. But the coding pattern is relatively easy to implement, and should fix the problem I described.

Comment: @dylanthelion We don't need any `CLLocationManager` in case of google maps. All we just need is to add keys in plist.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: I see the ViewController is a CLLocationManagerDelegate, which makes me think that the CLLocationManager is active, and should expose the user's location. I'm fine with recommending your GoogleMaps-specific answer, however.