# enable and disable location using UISwitch in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, navigation, swift4

I am working on google maps in which I want to show the location on google maps using `UISwitch`. I am able to show the location by using google Maps button but I don't know how can I do using `UISwitch`. As you can see in my 1st picture I am able to get the location but how can I do it by using `UISwitch`(I am using `MFSideMenu`) to display sidemenu. Any help?

[image]
[image]

```
         override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    setupSwitch()

    locManager = CLLocationManager()
    locManager.delegate = self
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error while getting location\(error)")
    }



}

func setupSwitch() {
    locationSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
        @objc func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    //Called when yourSwitch change its value
    if locationSwitch.isOn {
         menuContainerViewController.toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion({
    //self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()

              })
    } else {
        //Stops the location updates.
        self.locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

   private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    _ = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 17.0)


    //Finally stop updating location otherwise it will come again and again in this delegate
    self.locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

This is the code I wrote but it seems not working

Answer (score 2):

[UISwitch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch?language=objc) is a [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol?language=objc) object, so as apple's documentation says:

> Controls use the target-action mechanism to report interesting events
>   happening to your code.

What you need to use is the method [addTarget(_:action:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) and use the event [valueChanged](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents/1618238-valuechanged).

In your case your code might look something like this:

```
     func setupSwitch {
       yourSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
     }

     func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
         //Called when yourSwitch change its value
        if locationSwitch.isOn {
             //Starts tracking the user's current location.
             self.locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
             //Stops the location updates.
             self.locManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }      
     }
```

Also you can set the `valueChanged`  action from the *.xib* file.

Comment: but sir I want to update my location on home screen. Does this answer update my location on google map if I use addTarget method instead of outlet

Comment: Ok I am a little bit confused about your problem. As you said "I am able to get the location" I thought that your problem was just with the UISwitch class. If you want to show your current location in the google map you need to follow this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627279/8948781).

Comment: my problem is how can I show current location when switch is turn on and the code I wrote above is not working

Comment: Ok but I think you have enough information to resolve your problem. The code that I have posted will enable you to execute code when the switch is turn on/off (in my example if the switch is turn on it will start getting the user location) and the link that I have added in my last code will allow you to show the user's current location in map.

Comment: I used ur answer u can see above the problem I am getting is it is not showing the blue dot when switch is on

Comment: Do you tried using the `.isMyLocationEnabled` of the class `GMSMapView`? Try setting that property to `true` when getting the location.

Comment: Well Sir how can I access  GMSMapView from sidemenu I implemented this method in home view controller but how can I access it from sidemenu

Comment: That is another problem and is something that you need to figure out by restructuring your code.

Comment: Okay If I getting the problem I ask here Sir again thanks for giving your time Sir