# didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation for google maps ios swyft

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I recently switch my map from mapkit to google maps. However  i am tying to update user locations coordinates to firebase. What is the google equivalent to MKUserLocation

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        UpdateService.instance.updateALocation(withCoordinate: userLocation.coordinate)
        UpdateService.instance.updateBLocation(withCoordinate: userLocation.coordinate)
```

i want to be able to update the coordinates in real time to firebase with coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is **Google Maps doesn't have an equivalent method**. Google Maps is a third party from iOS perspective. So just like every other apps, they also have to use Apple's core location library to get the user location. Even the MKMapView also is using the CLLocationManager internally. You need to use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate method.

You can refer this answer to know about the use of core location in google maps.https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627279/4637057

So in your case, if you want to send the location coordinates to Firebase, then inside `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` access the `locations.last?.coordinate.latitude!` and `locations.last?.coordinate.longitude!`